# Обернуть текст поста в параграф p в Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

Вывожу превью текста статьи в таком виде:

**index.php:**

```
<div class="post__content">
...

     <?php mytheme_excerpt(70); ?>
...
</div>
```

**function.php:**

```
  /** Replaces "[...]" (appended to automatically generated excerpts) with ...   and a 'Continue reading' link. */

function mytheme_excerpt($limit) {
    $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt)."<a href='" .get_permalink($post->ID) ." ' class='link'>...</a>";
    echo $excerpt;
}
```

Через админку ввожу текст статьи.

**Ожидания:**

```
<div class="post__content">
...

     <p> Lorem ipsum .... </p>
...
</div>
```

**Реальность:**

```
<div class="post__content">
...

     Lorem ipsum .... 
...
</div>
```

Отсутствует тег `<p> </p>`.

**Вопрос:** как программно сделать так, чтобы при добавлении текста статьи, он оборачивался в параграф `<p></p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/** Replaces "[...]" (appended to automatically generated excerpts) with ...   and a 'Continue reading' link. */

function mytheme_excerpt($limit) {
$excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
array_pop($excerpt);
$excerpt = "<p>".implode(" ",$excerpt)."<a href='" .get_permalink($post->ID) ." ' class='link'>...</a></p>";
echo $excerpt;
}
```

Comment: Так все превью обернуто в параграф, а если у меня в превью 2-3 маленьких параграфа, которые вмещаются в превью. 

Т.е. мне нужно к примеру такое:

`<p> lfjhgdfhjghdj </p>
<p> lfjhgdfhjghdj </p>
< href="#" class="more" > ... </a>`

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: А эти параграфы есть в тексте статьи, введенном через админку?
Или их надо добавить?